# Specifying condition operator (AND/OR) for a column based on another column value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `recipe` table with a many-to-many to a `recipe_filter` table. Here's some sample data:

`recipe`:

```
id |   name
----+-----------
  1 | test 2019
 12 | slug-14
  8 | dfadsfd
  6 | test 4
  4 | test 2
 11 | slug-11
 10 | Testology
 13 | slug-15
  5 | test 3
 14 | slug-16
(10 rows)
```

`recipe_filter_join`:

```
 recipeId | recipeFilterId
----------+----------------
        1 |              1
        2 |              2
        3 |              3
        4 |              1
        6 |              5
        7 |              6
        8 |              4
        9 |              7
        6 |              8
       14 |              9
       14 |              4
        5 |              9
        5 |             38
```

`filter`:

```
id |         slug         |    name     |     label
----+----------------------+-------------+----------------
  2 | fdsfa                | fdsfa       | Category
  3 | dsfds                | dsfds       | Category
  6 | fdsaf                | fdsaf       | Category
  7 | dfad                 | dfad        | Category
  8 | product-spice-2      | Spice #2    | Product
  9 | product-spice-3      | Spice #3    | Product
  5 | product-spice-4      | Spice #4    | Product
  4 | product-spice-5      | Spice #5    | Product
  1 | product-spice-6      | Spice #6    | Product
 10 | product-spice-1      | Spice #1    | Product
 40 | diet-halal           | Halal       | Diet
 38 | diet-keto            | Keto        | Diet
 41 | diet-gluten-free     | Gluten free | Diet
 37 | diet-vegan           | Vegan       | Diet
 39 | diet-diabetic        | Diabetic    | Diet
 42 | cooking-method-bake  | Bake        | Cooking method
 43 | cooking-method-fry   | Fry         | Cooking method
 44 | cooking-method-steam | Steam       | Cooking method
 45 | cooking-method-roast | Roast       | Cooking method
(19 rows)
```

The input to my query is a list of `filters`.`slug`s for example `product-spice-1`, `product-spice-5`, `cooking-method-fry`, `cooking-method-steam`.

For the above example, I want to write a query that gets all recipes where the filter slug is (`product-spice-1` or `product-spice-5`) and (`cooking-method-fry` or `cooking-method-steam`).

How do I create a generic query from the example above?

**Update**: In case it's not clear, for the list of `filter`s given, I want to group them based on `label` and apply an OR between group members and an AND condition for other groups, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `INTERSECT` two queries

```
SELECT
rfj."recipeId"
FROM recipe_filter_join rfj
JOIN filter ON filter.id = rfj."recipeFilterId"
WHERE filter.slug IN ('product-spice-1','product-spice-5')
INTERSECT
SELECT
rfj."recipeId"
FROM recipe_filter_join rfj
JOIN filter ON filter.id = rfj."recipeFilterId"
WHERE filter.slug IN ('cooking-method-fry', 'cooking-method-steam')
```

And this is is quite generalizable. As you can see, the only difference between the two parts is in the WHERE clause. If you have other conditions on Diet or category, you could generate the appropriate query string with the variation on filer & join them with `INTERSECT` as the separator in your programming language of choice.

> I want to group them based on label and apply an OR between group members and an AND condition for other groups.

If you would prefer to have your application code call the query with just a list of slugs, then the following solution is more general.

If we restate the problem description as :

> We want to search for recipes which have ingredients intersecting with the provided ingredient list, and *the distinct labels for the recipes equals the distinct labels derived from the ingredient list* (this last part is handled by the having clause)

We can write

```
WITH distinct_labels AS (
  SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT label ORDER BY label) distinct_labels_filtered 
  FROM filter
  WHERE slug IN ('product-spice-1','product-spice-5','cooking-method-fry', 'cooking-method-steam')
)

  SELECT
  rfj."recipeId"
  FROM filter
  JOIN recipe_filter_join rfj
    ON filter.id = rfj."recipeFilterId"
  WHERE slug IN ('product-spice-1','product-spice-5','cooking-method-fry', 'cooking-method-steam')
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT label ORDER BY label) = (SELECT distinct_labels_filtered FROM distinct_labels)
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Could you explain what's happening with second example? Why do we group by 1?